# Does a script with async attribute execute on a separate thread or the same thread as the HTML parser in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, asynchronous, rendering

using defer or async attribute on a script tag causes it to be downloaded on a separate thread so that HTML parsing is not blocked. But once the script is downloaded, for async attribute, it will immediately execute.

1. Does this mean that it is executed on a separate thread as well.
2. I don't know much about threads but if answer to point 1. is YES, will the async script thread then be able to access data from the HTML parser thread, like DOM elements(I know there's no guarantee that the said DOM element will be available) or any metadata about document.
3. If the answer to point 1. is NO, and the async script is executed on the same thread as HTML Parser, then the parser will be blocked until the script finishes execution in which case we fail to achieve the optimization that we didn't want the page render to be blocked.
4. If the answer to point 1. is still NO, but it is the case that once async scripts are downloaded, the HTML parser thread first completes the execution of parser and only then executes the scripts, then what is the point of having defer since they are behaving in the same manner.

Comment: JavaScript is not multi-threaded, everything executes in the same thread.

Comment: The browser is multi-threaded, so it can use one thread for downloading and another thread for running JS. That's where the benefit of `async` and `defer` come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. There's only one thread for executing JavaScript (I'm ignoring WebWorkers, but they have to be invoked explicitly in your code).
2. N/A because the answer to #1 is no.
3. It will block the parser, but only after it has finished downloading the script. So there will be parsing taking place in parallel to waiting for the script to download. This can be quite significant, since the network is much slower than CPUs.
4. `defer` has the same benefit of parallelism that `async` has. But since it doesn't run until the document is fully parsed, it can refer to any elements that were loaded in the document. It's similar to putting the entire script in a listener for the `DOMContentLoaded` event (deferred scripts are actually run just before that event fires, so they can create elements that will be visible to listeners).

If you don't use `async`, the parser is blocked while waiting for the script to download *and* while it's executing, not just while the script is executing.